# How can I add the digits of number into another variable in the same order?

Tags: c++

I have to get the unit digit and the hundreds digit and put the in a variable in this order so I get a 2 digit number from a 3 digit one.
For example I have: x = 123, I want to have a variable y = 13.
I know how to get every digit individually but, I don't know how to put them into the number without using += and getting 4 instead of 13.

Comment: Remember that shifting digits in ten-based numbers can by done by multiplying / dividing with 10.

Comment: If you have the digits, just multiply the first by 10 and then add them together? `1*10 + 3` instead of `1 + 3`.

Comment: y = (x/100) + ((x % 100) % 10)

Comment: Thanks guys. I am dumb and forgot that I can multiply by ten. Sorry for the bother

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches come to mind:

- Parse the numbers as strings and remove the middle character from the string
- Use `/` and `%` to isolate the digits mathematically.

This is an example of the second approach:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  int input = 423;

  int digit_1 = input / 100; // int division drops the remainder
  int digit_2 = input % 10;  // modulus division saves the remainder only

  int answer = digit_1 * 10 + digit_2; 
  std::cout << answer << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```